# python filter returns none if any one input is not present in combination django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

i am creating a model in for a literature in which we can type english,german,french etc.. , my model may be containing english,german,french. if i put these 3 values in it , it shows me correct output but if type english,german it returns none because one condition failed, but in fact i want it in such a way that it return that perticular object if that condition met,  if i write english,german,french and model contains only english,german it should return english,german instead of none

```
def resolve_codepool_advanced_lang5(root,info,lang1,lang2,lang3,lang4,lang5):
        return Codepool_Advanced.objects.filter(codepool_advanced_language1=lang1,codepool_advanced_language2=lang2,codepool_advanced_language3=lang3,codepool_advanced_language4=lang4,codepool_advanced_language5=lang5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use **Q objects**

```py
from django.db.models import  Q


def resolve_codepool_advanced_lang5(root,info,lang1,lang2,lang3,lang4,lang5):
        return Codepool_Advanced.objects.filter(Q(codepool_advanced_language1=lang1)| Q(codepool_advanced_language2=lang2)| Q(codepool_advanced_language3=lang3)| Q(codepool_advanced_language4=lang4)| Q(codepool_advanced_language5=lang5))
```

To summarise the above query,
The query is checking if codepool_advanced_language1=lang1 or codepool_advanced_language2=lang2 or codepool_advanced_language3=lang3 and so on.

"|" is an **OR** Operator

You can learn more about django Q objects [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

**EDIT:**
Adding additional answer based on the comment made by the Author of the question.

Yes, there's a solution

```py
def resolve_codepool_advanced_lang5(root,info,lang1,lang2,lang3,lang4,lang5):
    languages = [lang1,lang2,lang3,lang4,lang5]
    return Codepool_Advanced.objects.filter(Q(codepool_advanced_language1__in=languages)| Q(codepool_advanced_language2__in=languages)| Q(codepool_advanced_language3__in=languages)| Q(codepool_advanced_language4__in=languages)| Q(codepool_advanced_language5__in=languages))
```

You can have all the languages in the list and you can use it like,

eg: `Q(codepool_advanced_language1__in=languages)|Q(codepool_advanced_language2__in=languages)|` and so on.

Comment: it worked thanks, but one more doubt if english is present in lang2 model and if we type english in lang 4 model it shows empty value, is there any solution for this

Comment: I have updated the answer with the solution for your comment. I would also suggest you to look into you db scheme and see how you could normalise it, Its is not advisable to have different fields for different languages. Try creating a seperate Model for languages and have a mapping model for Languages Model and Codepool_Advanced Model or you could have a language Many2Many field in the Codepool_Advance Model, I'm not aware of your exact use case, but i hope this helps.